# How to Search for row with Json Array Value as a condition in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table,

t_offices

```
id    name           offices

2     london     {"officeIds": [1, 33, 13, 1789]}

3     bangkok    {"officeIds": [2, 3, 40, 19]}
```

I can get the array in the json body using

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(p.`offices`, '$.officeIds[*]')  from t_offices p
```

It leads to

```
[1, 33, 13, 1789]
[2, 3, 40, 19]
```

But Now, How to search with a condition that it would have value 33.
i.e
`2 London {"officeIds": [1, 33, 13, 1789]}`

basically, get the row where a value is inside that json array.

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM t_offices WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(offices->'$.officeIds', '33');`

Comment: You would less problem with a normalised design

Comment: No need of `JSON_EXTRACT` Try `select * FROM t_offices where offices like '%33%'`

Comment: @SelVazi imagine that some array contains `1335`...

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(offices, '33', '$.officeIds')` is more correct. And more fast - it needs in one JSON parsing only.

Comment: @Akina Yes. You are right. Thanks for helping me to optimize query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM t_offices WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(offices, '33', '$.officeIds');
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM t_offices WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(offices->'$.officeIds', '33');
```